# Android url.openstream() throws fileNotFound

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access the output of a Url via url.openStream(). But it throws a FileNotFoundException. The weird thing is, that I have nearly the same code in another spot and it does work. When I click the Url manually the desired output ist viewed on the page. It also worked to this point. But somehow it can't establish a connection.

I tried to connect via Url.openConnection() and then get the stream with connection.getInputStream() but it also couldn't connect.

```java
URL url = new URL(urlReady);
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

```java
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://[URL HERE]
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1072)
        at de.david.taco.charityapp.DBOs.UserGetter$UserGetterTask.doInBackground(UserGetter.java:71)
        at de.david.taco.charityapp.DBOs.UserGetter$UserGetterTask.doInBackground(UserGetter.java:56)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Is that the real URL?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not set urlReady to a value, that can be found.
If it does, please provide what you set on new URL(); and what the Error is printing out

Comment: I printed out urlReady and when I clicked on it, it showed me the desired output